# How to run a python3 script remotely trough ssh

Tags: python, expect

I am trying to run a python3 script remotely trough ssh, first of all i would like to know if this is even possible if the machine i am trying to run the script on doesnt have a python3 interpreter only a 2001 version of python.

And also i am using the following command to run the script , but its not working:

```
spawn sh -c "ssh -oPort=$port $ip /usr/bin/env < /home/pythonscript
```

Pythonscript contains a command meant to output the connected COM ports,it is  the following:

```
import serial.tools.list_ports
print([comport.device for comport in serial.tools.list_ports.comport()])
```

The output that i get from this is a bunch of system information belonging to the machine i am connecting to, stuff like HOSTNAME,USER,MACHTYPE,MAIL,SHELL,OSTYPE

How would i get my intended output from the command that i am executing

All help appreciated

Comment: Can you please be more explicit with what problems/errors you are running into and any attempts you have made to resolve them?

Comment: the problem that i am running into is that my python script tell me what COM ports i have active, but the output i am getting from running the script remotely is a bunch of system information , which i am pretty sure is just information i get from running the ssh connection successfully, i want to know whats wrong somewhere in my code, that is making the script not run on the remote machine, i have tried to change the shebang on the spawn ssh command to various things but it has not worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly you will need to install python3 on each server you will be running this on. You will also need to install pip3 and install pyserial. You could also use virtualenv if you want but I'll leave that to you.

Found a small bug in that script. According to the latest version anyway it's "comports" not "comport: https://pyserial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tools.html

Updated Version:

```
from serial.tools.list_ports import comports
print([comport.device for comport in comports()])
```

I was able to run that remotely simply by doing the following

`ssh localhost "python3 /home/user/projects/stack_overflow/56900773_remote_python_ssh/pythonscript.py"`

Change localhost to whatever server you want and swap my path for the full path to your script.

When I ran that command I just get a blank list, probably because I have no comports :)